# Анимации на wow.js — есть ли способ добавить свою CSS3 анимацию, не из animate.css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, анимация, css-animation

В проекте уже подключены wow.js и animate.css для анимаций по скроллу.

Если ли способ подключить свою анимацию через wow.js - например добавив ее в файл animate.css? Или просто указав имя класса в wow.js по аналогии?

Т.е. использовать в подобной конструкции

```
<div class="wow MY-OWN-ANIMATION" data-wow-delay="1.0s">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете добавлять любые свои анимации, посмотрите как они реализованы в animate.css запускает их класс animated, если же нужно чтобы их запускал другой класс, то вот:

```
var wow = new WOW(
  {
    boxClass:     'wow',      // класс, скрывающий элемент до момента     отображения на экране (по умолчанию, wow)
    animateClass: 'animated', // класс для анимации элемента (по умолчанию,         animated)
  }
);
wow.init();
```